# Access the router params from within typescript vue component class

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-router

how can i access the params of the vue router within a typescript vue class?

See the screenshot attached, typescript complains.. are there some types i need to install?

[image]

The only way i can seem to get this working is to:
1 - import the router as illustrated in the image
2 - access the params via string literals:

```
router['history'].current.params.hash
```

But this breaks the linter

> object access via string literals is disallowed

And rightly so, i don't want to remove this rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue-router provides another [`$route`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object) object to represent the state of the current route. So, if you need to access the params of the route you need to use `this.$route.params` instead of `this.$router`.

Also, you need not install any types as vue-router already comes with its types definition.

Comment: doh! I missed that, was going around in circles. Thank you very much :)